# Chat server on node.js (NowJS) with features found in XMPP?

Tags: node.js, xmpp, socket.io, chat

I am looking for a chat server written in node.js, I am looking for something I can extend.

can anyone suggest something that is out there that supports at least a minimal amount of features out of the box, I don't mind getting my hands dirty and extending it, actually lookin forward to it.

I know something called NowJS existed but it appears that it isn't actively being developed anymore.

I was looking for some features like XMPP offers, i.e. Pub/Sub,  sending images, contacts ... this was noramlly done with XML...

Anyone using something like this... The only one i found was chat.io but i was hoping for something with a litle more out of the box functionality.

Also to use websockets out of the box

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.IO might be something you are looking for:

http://socket.io/